# count matches and mismatches group by

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk, perl

Please help with a shell script of the following.
I need count number of consistent variables in each lane (col1) across samples (col2). For example, since all the values (col4) of lane1 variable 1 accross all theree samples are the sample, variable1   is counted towards a consistent variable. Similarly, lane 2 variables 2 and 3 are both inconsistent.

```
lane1  sample1 variable1 ab
lane1  sample2 variable1 ab
lane1  sample3 variable1 ab   


lane1  sample1 variable2 cd
lane1  sample2 variable2 cd
lane1  sample3 variable2 cd

lane1  sample1 variable3 gh
lane1  sample2 variable3 ab
lane1  sample3 variable3 gh

lane2  sample1 variable1 ac
lane2  sample2 variable1 ac
lane2  sample3 variable1 ac


lane2  sample1 variable2 gt
lane2  sample2 variable2 gt
lane2  sample3 variable2 ac

lane2  sample1 variable3 ga
lane2  sample2 variable3 ga
lane2  sample3 variable3 ac
```

Output

Number of consistent and inconsistent variables accross all three samples

```
      #Consistent #Inconsistent
lane1  2             1
lane2  1             2
```

Comment: Are those lines always grouped in threes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my %values;
while (<>) {
    next if /^$/; # Skip empty lines
    my ($lane, $sample, $var, $val) = split;
    die "Duplicate $lane $sample $var\n" if $values{$lane}{$var}{$val}{$sample};
    $values{$lane}{$var}{$val}{$sample} = 1;
}

my %results;
for my $lane (keys %values) {
    for my $var (keys %{ $values{$lane} }) {
        my $count = keys %{ $values{$lane}{$var} };
        if (1 == $count) {
            ++$results{$lane}{consistent};
        } else {
            ++$results{$lane}{inconsistent};
        }
    }
    say join "\t", $lane, @{ $results{$lane} }{qw{ consistent inconsistent }};
}
```

Comment: @HiaSen: what's wrong with the solution?

Comment: the solution is perfect !! I accepted your answer, pardon me if I did some wrong clicks.. the only concern is if all the values are matching, then it gives a warning message regarding joins..I will post that in a little bit